# Errno 13 Permission on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I run the python code and seems to hit permission problem on Mac. I should have the admin rights of my own Mac. Why is that?

Code:

```
import os

os.makedirs(os.path.join('..', 'data'), exist_ok=True)
```

Message:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e97ad01ce9aa> in <module>
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 os.makedirs(os.path.join('..', 'data'), exist_ok=True)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    221             return
    222     try:
--> 223         mkdir(name, mode)
    224     except OSError:
    225         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../data'
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually only have admin rights on the mac with command run with `sudo`.

```
± touch /var/log/banana
touch: /var/log/banana: Permission denied 

± sudo touch /var/log/banana
± ls /var/log/banana
/var/log/banana
```

So you could either run your Python code with `sudo` (make sure you know what your code is doing as you could easily break you mac by deleting a file you didnt mean to) or much prefered! just write to a directory in say your `Users` directory where you have permissions anyway