# How to check App permission in mac os | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am a new Mac User.

I am making a **Python** Application which takes screenshots. It works perfectly in *Linux* and *Windows*. When I open my app (in *Mac*); I noticed that I have to give permission in `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `Screen Recording` and then allow apps to record screen.

I turned Screen Recording on and after a while I turned it off. Now when I reopened my app, Mac did not asked the prompt if I have to give rights. And also it was not able to access Screen.

Well, how can I check if user has enabled the permission in python? Something like this.

**file.py**

```py
if check_permission():
    perform_task()
else:
    if ask_permission:
        perform_task()
    else:
        print("You do not have enough rights")
```

Correct me if I am wrong. I am new to Mac. Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You might find some help reading the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018753/errno-13-permission-on-macos).